# Java GridBagLayout changing column size

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I'm using gridbaglayout for layout manager. And its size 6*10. But when i change jlabel text that inside gridbaglayout all columns auto resized. How can i prevent this behavior? I wanna column and row size be fixed.

Comment: That is how a column works. The width of a column is the width of the largest component added to the column. Maybe you want a GridLayot. The size of all cells will be the same and the grid will be sized to fill the space available in the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `GridBagConstraints.gridwidth` constraint. ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)).

```
 GridBagConstraints gs=new GridBagConstraints();

/* It specify the number of columns in the component's display area */
 gs.gridwidth=3;
```

Comment: Ok. I got it. If i will give preferred size with lblName.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(178, 15)); it's size fixed and doesn't change the column size.